# Pandas to_csv stop to update file even if multiprocessing task is not finished

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, queue

I am using a `Queue` to append csv file during python `mutliprocessing` task. The maximum size of the CSV file is not always the same i.e. depending of the number of tasks to be performed, the size could be 5 Gb or 2.5 Gb. I suspect an earlier stop of the CSV update function , but could not find the issue. Do you have any idea?

Please find part of by code:

```
def csv_file_writer(dest_filename, some_queue, some_stop_token):
    """
    Print the data to the CSV File
    :param dest_filename:
    :param some_queue:
    :param some_stop_token:
    :return:
    """
    while True:
        data = some_queue.get()

        if data == some_stop_token: return
        pandas_dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

        # convert numpy array to string
        pandas_dataset['Image_Grayscale'] = pandas_dataset['Image_Grayscale'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))
        pandas_dataset['Image_RGB'] = pandas_dataset['Image_RGB'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))
        pandas_dataset['Image_Segmentation'] = pandas_dataset['Image_Segmentation'].apply(lambda x: np.array2string(x, separator=','))

        # Save the into the CSV File
        if not os.path.exists(dest_filename): pandas_dataset.to_csv(dest_filename, mode='w', header=True, index=False)
        if os.path.exists(dest_filename): pandas_dataset.to_csv(dest_filename, mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

And in my Main function:

```
m = Manager()
global csv_file_writting_queue
csv_file_writting_queue = m.Queue()
STOP_TOKEN="STOP!!!"
writer_process = Process(target=csv_file_writer, args=(xray_dataset_main_directory + xray_dataset_csvfile_filename + '.csv', csv_file_writting_queue, STOP_TOKEN))
writer_process.start()

with Pool(processes=nb_cores_to_be_used) as pool_image_generation:
    for dictionary in tqdm.tqdm(pool_image_generation.istarmap(image_generation_function_dispatching, data), total=len(data), miniters=1):
        # collect results from the workers through the pool result queue
        #csv_writting_q.put(dictionary)
        if dictionary is not None: csv_file_writting_queue.put(dictionary)

pool_image_generation.close()
pool_image_generation.join()
csv_file_writting_queue.put(STOP_TOKEN)
writer_process.join()
```

CSV File Info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 71262 entries, 0 to 71261
Data columns (total 58 columns):
Column_Size                                71262 non-null int64
Gaussian_Filter                            71262 non-null float64
Image_Class_Name                           71262 non-null object
Image_Grayscale                            71262 non-null object
Image_Id                                   71262 non-null int64
```

Comment: As an aside, since the pool is in a with clause, you don't need pool close and join afterwards.

Comment: As a second aside, you are assuming that the dataframe always has columns in the same order when you write the csv. You run the risk that some to_csv calls will write in a different order, corrupting data. Better to use the `columns=[...]` parameter to make the order well defined.

Comment: Your code looks good except I'd add some exception handling to the worker. You could keep counts in the parent of total dictionaries and non-null dictionaries actually passed to the subprocess, plus a count in the subprocess itself. The passed dicts and processed dict counts should be the same.

Comment: @tdelaney, Regarding your comments on the columns, as I transfered a dictionary to a dataframe and then to to_csv, I thought columns are identified and no corrupted data could occur. The issue I have is some columns are always the same, the number of the others could depend from a parameter at the begining of the task. This parameter is never updated during the task.

Comment: dict keys enumerate in insertion order. Lets say your first dict adds columns A, B, C. But your second dict has slightly different processing and adds them B, A, C. Now, when you create that second dataframe and to `to_csv`, it will write the columns in a different order. B will be in A column.

Comment: @tdelaney, my code has been updated based on all of your proposals. Based on test performed, sometimes the Queue is treated at the end of the multiprocessing task. 
Do you know if it is possible to force write csv file when a max items number is reached in the Queue ? Indeed, it could be very helpful to avoid potential memory overflow.